# How to define specific mapping in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I need to parse my data like

```
root:[group:[instance:[hourly:{},monthly:{},daily:{}]]]
```

how to define mappings to get data like this?

Comment: Can you share a sample log line that you want to parse?

Comment: You need to specify sample input and output.